# Excel: COUNTIFS or Nested IF counting sequential columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

this is my first time posting here so please be a little patient with me. I'm trying to write a formula that will tracked missed scan events (for a package tracking database).

I have several date/time columns that are in sequential order of the shipping process. First scan event is column 1, second is column 2, until the package is delivered in column 8.

I want to track columns that have a missing date/timestamp inbetween columns. For instance, if column 1, column 2, column 5 have timestamps, I want to count columns 3 and 4 as a missed scan. I would not count colums 6-8 as missed as they had no future timestamps and probably just haven't happened yet.

Can anyone help me with this? I'm including a screenshot of my data. In the screenshot, I would want "NULL" values in column 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 to be counted as missed scans, because there are timestamps after them.[missedscans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amX9l.png)

Answer (score 1):

Create a dynamic range with INDEX/MATCH.

For example if your date are true dates then they are numbers and this:

```
INDEX(A2:H2,MATCH(1E+99,A2:H2))
```

Will return the last cell in the range that has a date.

So using:

```
A2:INDEX(A2:H2,MATCH(1E+99,A2:H2))
```

We return a range between the start and the last cell with a date.

then we just count the `NULL`s in that range:

```
=COUNTIF(A2:INDEX(A2:H2,MATCH(1E+99,A2:H2)),"NULL")
```

[image]

Comment: I am still working on integrating this into my spreadsheet, but if I can get it to work as your example shows, then it should be EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Now, I didn't realize until I saw this working, I am looking for another thing in addition to this. I'm wondering if there's a way to get the header value (A, B, C, etc in your example) so that I can track where the missed scans were. For example, cell I2 must know somewhere that its "1" value is coming from cell C2. Would it be more complex of a return for cell value greater than 1 in column I? Any thoughts on this?